# ReactJs - rendering problem. why my signout button show up after refresh?

Tags: reactjs, rendering, mern

can somebody help me. i just wanna know, after i get the data user from localstorage. the signout button will show up after i refresh the page. can somebody help me pls? thank you

here's the code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './header.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem('user')
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).token
      : ''
  );

  const signOuthandler = (e) => {
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    setToken();
  };

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        {!token && (
          <>
            <li>
              <Link to="/login">
                <button>Sing in</button>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/register">
                <button>Register</button>
              </Link>
            </li>
          </>
        )}
        {token && (
          <>
            <li>
              <Link onClick={signOuthandler} to="/login">
                <button>Sing Out</button>
              </Link>
            </li>
          </>
        )}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: i don't see where you are updating the state when login in so to re-render the new ui!!

Answer (score -1):

update your sign out token in 'useEffect',

```
useEffect(()=>{
   setToken(localStorage.getItem('user')
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).token
      : '')
},[localStorage.getItem('user')])
```